# Display sentences splitted, sorted and randomized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

Recently started to dive into coding with a little project. Basically I want to display the sentences (content) of an infinite number of html elements, splitted into 4 boxes, then bring the boxes into a random order and randomly display one of the boxed and differently sorted sentences based on the current minute. So for an element like the one below

```
<p id="ex1"  style="display:none" >The Chop’s popularity in Atlanta won’t soon abate, and even breaks out spontaneously when the Braves rally on the road (often to the irritation of the home team’s fans).</p>
```

[This result should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sw4R.png)

This is what I came up by my own so far on the splitting and sorting part for one element:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="ex1"  style="display:none" >{{Ex1}}</p>

<script>
var g1 = document.getElementById("ex1").textContent; ;
var g2=g1.split(" ");
var gx = g2.length;
var g3 = [];
if (gx <= 4) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 1){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 1));}}

else if (gx <= 8) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 2) { g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 2));}}
else if (gx <= 12) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 3){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 3));}}
else if (gx <= 16) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 4){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 4));}}
else if (gx <= 20) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 5){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 5));}}
else if (gx <= 24) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 6){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 6));}}
else if (gx <= 28) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 7){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 7));}}
else if (gx <= 32) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 8){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 8));}}
else if (gx <= 36) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 9){ g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 9));}}
else if (gx <= 40) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 10){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 10));}}
else if (gx <= 44) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 11){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i +11));}}
else if (gx <= 48) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 12){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 12));}}
else if (gx <= 52) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 13){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 13));}}
else if (gx <= 56) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 14){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 14));}}
else if (gx <= 60) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 15){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 15));}}
else if (gx > 60) {for(var i = 0; i < g2.length; i += 20){g3.push (g2.slice(i, i + 20));}}

(function () {
  // First sort the array
  g3.sort();
  // Then reverse it:
  g3.reverse(" ");
})();

var g4 = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < g3.length; i++) {
     g4 = g4 + "<li>" + g3[i] + "</li>"
 }

var g5 = g4.replace(/\,/g, '    ');
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = g5;

</script>
```

And this is my raw idea for randomly display element ex1:

```
<script>
var today = new Date();
var random = today.getMinutes()%3 + 1
if (today.getHours() <= 4) {
 random -= 1
}
if (random == 1) {
 $('#demo').show()
} else if (random == 2) {
 $('#demo2').show()
} else {
 $('#demo3').show()
}
</script>
```

My question would be how to scale these approaches for an infinite (actually up to 8) number of elements and their sentences like

```
<p id="ex1"  style="display:none" >The Chop’s popularity in Atlanta won’t soon abate, and even breaks out spontaneously when the Braves rally on the road (often to the irritation of the home team’s fans).</p>

<p id="ex2"  style="display:none" >The Chop’s popularity in Atlanta won’t soon abate, and even breaks out spontaneously when the Braves rally on the road (often to the irritation of the home team’s fans).</p>

<p id="ex3"  style="display:none" >But his attitude of sullen grievance and simmering fury never abated fully</p>

...
```

Clustering them by class (e.g. class=examples) and then loop through each of them? 
One really important condition for any approach would be, that if the randomly selected element doesn't have content (sentence) another element(sentence) should be displayed. Besides that an approach without jQuery would be perfect.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance for your time and support!

Comment: Regarding the duplicate code, the number used in the loop is `Math.ceil(gx / 4)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're going for though I may have misunderstood your question.

```js
const str = document.getElementById("ex1").textContent;
const words = str.split(' ');

//fill wordsByGroup[groupIndex] = sorted array of words in group
const wordsByGroup = [];
const groupSize = Math.ceil(words.length / 4);
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  wordsByGroup[i] = words
    .slice(i * groupSize, (i+1) * groupSize)
    .sort();
}

const minute = (new Date()).getMinutes();
const groupIndex = Math.floor(minute % 4);
const pickedGroup = wordsByGroup[groupIndex];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'For minute ' + minute + ': ' + pickedGroup.join(' ');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <p id="ex1"  style="display:none" >1 3 2 5 4 7 6 a 9 c b e d g f i h</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! The code already looks much better in your version! It also almost what I was looking for, although the whole sentence should be displayed and only the groups as a whole  should be  brought into a different order. This should  then be  applied to an indefinite number of elements  and one of  them should be displayed based on the current minute- if it has some content. I edited my post to clarify my question and also add a picture how the result should look like. Would be great if you could have a second look at it! Thank you again a lot for your support and time!